# How to Make Phone Calls Interrupt Music/Podcasts?

Tags: settings, nokia-lumia-920

On my Lumia 920, when listening to music or podcasts, and the phone in vibrate mode, I often do not notice the vibration for an incoming call.

Is there a way to set the phone to interrupt playback when there is an incoming call? My older phones did this, and if I was zoning out while listening and it was suddenly interrupted, I knew to look down at my phone to see if it was a call coming in.

Comment: Er, this works just like you want on my HTC 8X. Wish I could be more help, but definitely something wonky going on.

Comment: If you have the ringer turned on, the phone will stop playback and play the ringtone through your headset.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the ringer on and it will interrupt the music. It will later continue the music once you're done talking.